# jQuery mobile data-rel="back" link causing wrong events to be fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

Have a look at the [test-case](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16705233/data-rel-back.html)

When you open the link, `pagebeforeshow` for *page 1* is fired. When you click the link to go to *page 2*, `pagebeforeshow` for *page 2* is fired. So far, so good.

If you then use the left button (`data-rel="back"`) to go back, excess events are fired. Using the right button instead (direct link to *page 1*) does what I'd expect, namely, only `pagebeforeshow` for *page 1* gets fired.

`pagebeforeshow` can also be replaced with `pageshow`, doesn't matter. What's happening here?

(Tested in up-2-date Chrome)

Source for reference:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $('#test1').live('pagebeforeshow', function() {
          console.log("=== pagebeforeshow for #test1");
      });
      $('#test2').live('pagebeforeshow', function() {
          console.log("=== pagebeforeshow for #test2");
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="test1">

      <div data-role="header" align="center">
        <p>Page 1.</p>
      </div><!-- /header -->

      <div data-role="content">
        <p><a href="#test2">Go to page 2.</a></p>
      </div><!-- /content -->

    </div><!-- /page -->

    <div data-role="page" id="test2">

      <div data-role="header" align="center">
        <a href="/" data-icon="back" data-rel="back">Back</a>
        <p>Page 2.</p>
        <a href="data-rel-back.html" data-icon="back">Go directly to page 1</a>
      </div><!-- /header -->

      <div data-role="content">
        <p>
        Try the two buttons and have a look at the console.<br>
        Using the left button (data-rel="back") triggers "too many" events.<br>
        The right button does what I'd expect.
        </p>
      </div><!-- /content -->

    </div><!-- /page -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine in Firefox 7.

Comment: Works fine on Safari 5.1.1 as well. I get your error running Chrome though...

Comment: This has been answered by the following post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321655/jquery-mobile-data-rel-back-data-transition-does-not-work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Mobile: data-rel="back" + data-transition does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321655/jquery-mobile-data-rel-back-data-transition-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this is a [bug](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2762#issuecomment-2470768) in Chrome's console.

Chromium [bugtracker](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=101038)

Answer (score 1):

Please change the link to redirect to page 1

```
<a href="data-rel-back.html" data-icon="back">Go directly to page 1</a>
```

should be

```
<a href="/#test1" data-icon="back">Go directly to page 1</a>
```

if you find any trouble with this remove forward slash

```
 <a href="#test1" data-icon="back">Go directly to page 1</a>
```

Comment: In the original version I had a two html-page setup. I've only merged them for this example. That's why I'm linking to the .html. Shouldn't make a difference in this as example as JQM automatically fetches the first page in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Live [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/k6b3v/4/)

Corrected tags in header and back button attributes

```
<a data-rel="back">Back</a>
```

jQM adds extra markup when rendering the page, if you use the wrong tags some of the functionality might change, break. I think what was happening for the back button is you also added a href="/" attribute and this might have caused jQM to try to navigate to it as well as going back to the last page causing the issue.

Also in the header you had used the `<p>` tag and aligned it center, jQM does this when using the `<h1>`

For more on the back button you can always refer to the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html)

Comment: The JQM docs mention explicitly that you should also define a "href" attribute for clients that (for some reason) don't support the back functionality.

Apart from that, your code changes still produce exactly the same result as before for me.

In the original application there is an image in the center, that's why I don't use <h1>.