# jQuery Mobile: data-rel="back" + data-transition does not work?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I created a jsfiddle that enables tabs using the navbar without changing the url hash: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanhaney/eLENj/

1) If I click on the "page 1" link from the home page, followed by clicking the "back" button, I get the reverse slide animation as expected.

2) If I click on the "page 1" link from the home page, then click on "page 2" or "page 3" (in the footer navbar), then click on the "back" button....there is no transition.

If I follow scenario #2 after changing the "$.mobile.changePage" call in the jsfiddle javascript to use a transition other than "none", the back button uses that same transition.

How can I enforce the transition for elements with data-rel="back"?

NOTE: In the jsfiddle example, it is desired behavior to keep tab selections out of the navigation history.  The back button should go back home regardless of which tab you are on.  There should be no transition between tabs.  The jsfiddle example already provides this behavior.

Comment: something: http://jsfiddle.net/eLENj/9/

Comment: Interesting that the alert changes behavior.  See my note above as your modification has somehow included that the tabs in the navigation history.

Comment: Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanhaney/E86M9/ which changes the transition based on the href. transition: anchor.attr("href") == "#page-3" ? "fade" : "none"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got it:

- http://jsfiddle.net/E86M9/3/

Had to reset the changePage default transition value

```
$("a[data-role=tab]").each(function () {
    var anchor = $(this);
    anchor.bind("click", function () {
        $.mobile.changePage(anchor.attr("href"), {
            transition: "none",
            changeHash: false
        });
        return false;
    });
});

$("div[data-role=page]").bind("pagebeforeshow", function (e, data) {
    $.mobile.silentScroll(0);
    $.mobile.changePage.defaults.transition = 'slide'; // reset default here
});​
```

HTML

```
<div id="home" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>
            <a href="#page-1">Page 1</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page-1" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Page 1 content</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page-1" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-active">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-2" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-3" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page-2" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Page 2 content</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page-1" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-2" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-active">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-3" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page-3" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
        <h1>Page 3</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Page 3 content</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page-1" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-2" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-3" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-active">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Marked as answer.  I think this is a bug in the way urlHistory gets processed.  Thanks!

Comment: add this as a bug to the jQM repo: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3599

Answer (score 0):

```
anchor.bind("click", function () {
$.mobile.changePage(anchor.attr("href"), {
    transition: "none",
    changeHash: false
});
return false;
```

Seems to be the issue with `"transition: "none","`. When I remove it or change it to anything, it works as you expect it: http://jsfiddle.net/PQsyP/

Comment: Actually, when I change the transition to "fade", if I go from home to page 1 and click back, I get the expected default slide transition.  But if I go from home to page 1 to page 2 and click back, the back transition becomes a fade.  Weird.

Comment: You are right. Modified the jsfiddle to remove the transition. Now the default slide is also on the tabs. Will play around with it to see how to specify it to the tabs.